# Polyline Animation Google Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline, google-polyline

I want to animate the polyline as in Uber IOS app but for android. I have used below link to achieve this but, there are some issues. When you draw a polyline, those points near the turns are not accurate, they are placed on top of the buildings and some times instead of a proper polyline there is a straight line from source to destination. What I want to do is the polyline must stick on to road no matter what! So How do i fix this? Or is there a library that I can use to

> animate a polyline

[Animate_polyline, that I have currently used](https://github.com/amalChandran/google-maps-route-animation)

Kindly help me out!

Comment: could u please take some screenshots to describe  your issue

Comment: The project is updated now. The routes that are drawn now actually stick to the roads.